# Update longitude / latitude with geocoder gem geocode by street address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, rubygems

How can I update the latitude and longitude coordinates using `geocoder` gem given the following models and relationship. I have a `Location` model with `latitude` and `longitude` attributes that belong to my `Event` model. The latitude and longitude automatically get fetched and stored in `latitude` and `longitude` attributes of my `Location` model. My `Event` model has a field `venue_address` which is what I geocode by.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
    geocoded_by :venue_address
    after_validation :geocode
end
```

AND this is my `Event` model with `has_one :location` relation

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one     :location,  dependent: :destroy
end
```

Next is my Event create method where I build the relationship.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    # Builds longitude and latitude coordinates based on a valid street address
    # and saves it to Location table
    @event.build_location
...
  end 
end
```

When I update the address of an event I would like to geocode the new coordinates and save the coordinates to their respective field in `Location` model.

I am having trouble accomplishing this. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Does tha location table contain 'venue_address' attribute?

Comment: whats the error and where you are getting.please elaborate

Comment: @Sravan the `Location` coordinates get fetch by the `geocode_by` method. To answer your question the `venue_address` is in the `Event` model.

Comment: If 'venue_addrress' is in event model, then 'geocoded_by :venue_address' should be taken in Event model.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  geocoded_by :event_venue_address
  after_validation :geocode

  def event_venue_address
    event.venue_address
  end

end
```

or just delegate to event model

```
delegate :venue_address, to: event, prefix: true
```

Here is the example for the [readme](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#model-configuration)

```
If your model has street, city, state, and country attributes you might do something like this:

geocoded_by :address

def address
  [street, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
end
```

Hope that helps